# Her prospects are good while his are bad when it comes to

Tags: grammar

The phrase pretty much sums it up.

Her prospects are good while his are bad when it comes to ___, where ___ can be anything, for the sake of exposition. In this case, although we are only specifying his prospects and what they are bad with respect to, something in this sentence implies that her prospects are good with respect to
the *same thing*.

Is there a way in which we can separate her prospects from his in this current usage?

Comment: 'While' in the comparison sense always involves some commonality. ??/*'His chances are good in the upcoming tennis tournament, while John's chances of getting off without being given a custodial sentence are slim.'

Comment: Welcome! Of course, if a construction is ambiguous, you can choose a different construction. Please edit to clarify: Are you asking if there's a way to force *this construction* to mean "Her [X, without regard to Y] are good while his are [bad when it comes to Y]"? Or are you asking for a good way to rephrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Her prospects are good while his are bad, when it comes to X,

**when it comes to X** is adverbial, and as such can be placed, in parenthesis as follows

When it comes to X, her prospects are good while [,when it comes to X,] his are bad,

Her prospects are good, when it comes to X, while his are bad [,when it comes to X,]

Her prospects are good [,when it comes to X,] while his are bad, when it comes to X,

and the implication (in square brackets) cannot be avoided.

You need to reconstruct:

**Their overall** prospects are good, **but**, when it comes to X, his are bad.

Answer (score 0):

> Her prospects are good while his are bad when it comes to passing the course.

This means she is likely to pass the course, while he is not likely to.

Dictionary reference from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prospect):

**Prospect** *noun*, definition 4 (d) (2) is  "chances"